# Is it necessary to specify id("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false?

Tags: android

I have seen that in my build.gradle (project level) I have no plugins. I have seen in the Firebase implementation that supposedly it is something that I should have since it is in gray color:

This is the first step in the official implementation of Firebase. This was not necessary a month ago to implement firebase.

```
plugins {
  id("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false
  // ...

  // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
  id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.3.15" apply false
}
```

My question is, regardless if I want to implement firebase or no, is it really necessary to specify `id("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false` ? Actually my app is working fine and I have no plugins at project build gradle...